# Import dynamic a typescript file in Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

According NextJs documentation we can use dynamic import for javascripts files`const DynamicComponent = dynamic(() => import('../components/hello'))`.

 Will be correct to use dynamic import also for `.tsx` file like this:

```js
const MyComponent = dynamic(() => import('main/my-file.tsx'), {
  ssr: false,
});
```

? Or we can import dynamically only `.js` files?

Comment: You can dynamically import both JavaScript and TypeScript modules.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you can dynamically import `ts` files in nextjs with some workarounds.

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
...
...
const Button = dynamic(() => import("../components/Button").then(module => module.default));
```

If you want to read further https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/4515

Comment: but in the way i wrote will work> Because i tried and looks ok like i did.